# Turning string into a section

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to turn, for example, "+3" into a (+3) in Haskell to use it later with the operand? I am trying to build some kind of "sequence-based calculator", which's using a foldl to evaluate. This foldl takes an operations (?) list [(+3),(*4),(/5)] and program's need to turn a string list into this. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell is a compiled language, so you usually can’t use strings containing code in the place of real code.¹

So the proper way to do it would be write a parser for such strings, i.e. a function

```
parseOp :: String -> (Integer -> Integer)
parseOp ...
```

that looks at the strings and returns the appropriate operation. If your operations are always just `×n`, this can be a simple pattern match on the list and an invocation to read. (I’ll leave that up to you.)

¹ <sup>You could link against the GHC-API and thus have a compiler being part of your program. But really, not in this case...</sup>